# save ArrayList from one class to other class

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to save ArrayList from `main()` into my new ArrayList which is subString in geTles(ArrayList input_list_of_strings). How do I do that? I know that we need to do with the loop and add it up to subString. Also I want to break down the string word that I have in my code into small subStrings. Example: "SCHOOLWORK"  will break down to "SC","HOO","LWO","RK".

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HW2 {

    public static ArrayList getTiles(ArrayList input_list_of_strings) {
        // create a substring by go through the loop first, then .... (instruction)
        ArrayList<String> subString = new ArrayList<>();
        return input_list_of_strings;       
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> input_words = new ArrayList<String>();
        input_words.add("SCHOOLWORK");
        input_words.add("BALCONY");
        input_words.add("INSIST");
        input_words.add("SALTPETER");
        input_words.add("BOLTON");
        input_words.add("KITSCHY");
        input_words.add("CLIENTELE");
        System.out.print(getTiles(input_words));    
    }
}
```

Comment: whats your creiteria for the split ?

Comment: oh, so how to save it into subString arrayList, then?

Comment: You need to be more clear with your question mate!

Comment: are you looking for `ArrayList.add`?

Comment: Give us your original question. You need to go read the ArrayList api, I don't think you know what an arraylist is or how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not saving anything.  You're passing the `ArrayList` into your method by value.  I'd also argue that it's pretty important that you design to the interface instead of the concrete implementation (that is, you'd be using `List` instead), and you type it so that the behavior you need in your method doesn't involve casts or temporary variables.

Here's what I mean.

```
public static List<String> getTiles(List<String> inputList) {
    // criteria for dividing up the strings themselves
    // logic to modify the list in-place or create a new copy to return
}
```